# Unstable cluster with hosts.xml resets to default

Tags: marklogic-9

While performing management api operations such as removing app servers from a MarkLogic cluster, it becomes unstable resetting hosts.xml to default/localhost setting.

Logs shows something like: 
MarkLogic: Slow send xx.xx.34.113:57692-xx.xx.34.170:7999, 4.605 KB in 1.529 sec; check host xxxx

Consider infrastructure is slow or not slow, but automatic recovery is still not happening.

How to overcome this situation?
Anyone who can provide more info on how management api is working under the hood?

Adding further details:

DELETE http://${BootstrapHost}:8002${serveruri}

POST http://${BootstrapHost}:8002${forest}?state=detach

DELETE http://${BootstrapHost}:8002${forest}?replicas=delete&level=full

DELETE http://${BootstrapHost}:8001/admin/v1/host-config?remote-host=${hostname}

When removing servers 1st request or removing host 4th request, few nodes in the cluster restarts and we check for nodes availability. However this is uncertain and sometimes hosts.xml resets to a default xml which says it is not part of any cluster.

How we fix, we copy hosts.xml from another host to this faulty host and it starts working again.

We found that it was very less likely to come in MarkLogic 8, but with MarkLogic 9 this problem is frequent and if it is on AWS it is even more frequent.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some more details about what you were trying do with the Management API (and example code or commands that you were executing). When you say that the cluster "becomes unstable resetting hosts.xml to default/localhost setting", do you mean that it becomes unstable and you then revert to previous hosts.xml (if so, how are you doing this), or that the Manage API commands aren't making the expected changes to hosts.xml?

Comment: I would also recommend reaching out to MarkLogic Support if that is possible.

Comment: Reached to the MarkLogic support, we use phoenix deployment, which add/remove nodes to the cluster frequently. As per their comment, MarkLogic does not support frequent addition and removal of the nodes. 
I don't know the internals but as per my observation it is because of few management api calls which leads to few hosts to restart and lead to unstable nodes, might be because they were still restarting.